# Doctrine Column-Aggregation Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, symfony1, doctrine, column-aggregation

I'm trying to implement Doctrine column-aggregation inheritance

I copied the Yaml structure from the [Doctrine guide](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/pl/inheritance%3acolumn-aggregation) and paste it in my `schema.yml` file:

```
Entity:
  columns:
    username: string(20)
    password: string(16)
    created_at: timestamp
    updated_at: timestamp

User:
  inheritance:
    extends: Entity
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: 1

Group:
  inheritance:
    extends: Entity
    type: column_aggregation
    keyField: type
    keyValue: 2
```

But when I use the `doctrine:build-model` and `doctrine:build-sql` commands from symfony's command line, the sql file I get contains two similar lines for creating the `Entity` table:

```
CREATE TABLE entity (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(16), created_at DATETIME, updated_at DATETIME, type VARCHAR(255), INDEX entity_type_idx (type), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE entity (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(16), created_at DATETIME, updated_at DATETIME, type VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Which ofcourse causes an error when I try to import it to my database..

Is it a build-in bug in Symfony's command-line?

Comment: Strange... are you up-to-date?

Comment: I think I am.. I have symfony 1.4.11 not sure about the Doctrine version

Comment: Do you know of any tool other than Symfony's CLI to build the .sql from my YAML file?

Comment: the latest version of symfony is 1.4.15 . There might have been some bugfixes in the embedded doctrine version. Please udpate. And no, I don't know any other tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like it is a [reported bug](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-123) and it will only work in Doctrine 2